# Spaces are removed from the element value automatically in displayed result

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am assigning the value of query to queryVal. If there is more than one space in the string it is automatically removed from the value shown on the webpage but In Debugging $("#queryVal").text() shows the value without any problem. 
for example, if the query is "abc  def    ghi"(spaces are removed here too) I get the value on the webpage abc def ghi.

```
    query = CreateQuery(currentDataSource, false);

    $("#queryVal").text("");
    $("#queryVal").text(query);

    if ((query == "" && queryFilter == undefined) || queryFilter == query) {
        DisableBtn("btnSaveQuery");
    }
    else {
        EnableBtn("btnSaveQuery");
    }
```

I dont know what is causing the problem

Comment: did you try using html(); instead of text()

Comment: its same with html();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how HTML works: A series of whitespace characters is displayed as a single space.

If you want to change that, apply one of the `pre`-like [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) styles to the element, e.g.:

```css
#queryVal {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

(Or use a `pre` element, of course.)

Example:

```js
$("#queryVal").text("There    are    multiple   spaces   here.");
```

```css
#queryVal {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="queryVal"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```